# How to referesh the DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to refresh the **DataTable** after changing in server side

Here i have define the dataTable when `isData= 1` at server side **mqsql(DB)**

```
function one()
{
var DataTableApp = $('#DataTableApp').dataTable({
"sAjaxSource": "php/getAppDetails.php",
....
....
}
```

when click the some one in **DataTable**. I have changed  `isData=0`, It is in ajax calling in another function.

After changing `isData=0`, I want to referesh the table..

How to referesh the **DataTable**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "php/removeApp.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            json_objApp = data;
            if(json_objApp.isSuccessful == true)
            {
                document.getElementById('removeAppSucc').innerHTML = "Successfully Removed";
                document.getElementById('collapseFive').setAttribute("class", "collapse");

                DataTableApp.fnDraw();
                DataTableApp._fnAjaxUpdate();

            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('removeAppSucc').innerHTML = "App is not removed"
            }
        },
});
```

Comment: see about [fnDraw](https://datatables.net/api#fnDraw)

Comment: I am using this at success:function()  after changing isData=0. but there is no response   document.getElementById('DataTableApp').fnDraw();

Comment: you do it wrong :-) `fnDraw` is api function for data table, in your case you try call this function from dom-object.

Comment: fnDraw() works. but if i remove when have two row, it will remove, but If i have only one row, it doesn't remove

Comment: can you provide little more code, i don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: success: function (data) {
            json_objApp = data; DataTableApp.fnDraw(); }

Comment: you can edit your post for adding more code

Comment: [allan suggest not using internal functions](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/15634/reload-table-content-using-_fnajaxupdate/p1)

Comment: possibly you need use [fnReloadAjax](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax) instead of `fnDraw` and `_fnAjaxUpdate`

Comment: also why you use both `fnDraw` and `_fnAjaxUpdate` i think `fnDraw` will be enough

Comment: I used both the functions but same issues there

Comment: `fnDraw` should redraw all table, so possibly error in serverside procedure that return data?